# How to give my address?

Tags: spoken-english, reading-aloud

I want to book a hotel room over telephone and I was wondering how I should give my address. I think the best way to do it is to spell it because I don't think the person at the hotel would be able to understand it otherwise. Also, should I say Street X, where X is the name of the street, or simply X?

Comment: Where is the hotel (UK? USA?), and what is the structure of an address in your native language and country?

Comment: It is in the UK and in my country we write street, flat/house number, building number. What puzzles me is that they have Address Line 1 and 2, but I figure that I only have to write building number and street in Line 1.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you give your address it's in the order: building number, street, unit number (if applicable), city, state/province, postal code, and possibly country (if applicable).  For example:

> 111 First Street Apartment 11, Onesville, California, 11111-1111, United States.

Naturally there are many variations depending on your country's address system.  In Japan they divide the city into districts rather than by street number, so for example the address to the Nintendo headquarters is:

> 11-1 Kamitoba-hokotate-cho, Minami-ku, Kyoto 601-8501, Japan.

Still, if you tell the person on the phone that you are going to give then your address, and you start with a number, the rest should be understood.

You may, of course, have to speak slowly (and even spell them out) if the place names are difficult for English speakers to understand.  But this is not unusual even with local place names.  I currently live on a street with a weird name, and usually have to spell it out when I'm on the phone.